# Direction of unit normal vector

Tags: calculus, geometry

Let $S$ be a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $z=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ where $x^2+y^2\leq1$. I need to make sure that the normal vector is pointing inwards. I have computed $N$ and found it to be $N=(-z\cos(\theta),-z\sin(\theta),z)$.

How can I tell if this points inwards or not?

Comment: _Hint_: as you've written it, the vector will always point inwards.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel How do you know that?

Comment: Your equation, in polar coordinates, is $z=r$. The graph looks like a cone, and if the normal vector is to be pointing inwards it must be pointing towards the inside of that cone, i.e. the $z$ component must be upwards, which it is.

Comment: The question title says _unit_ normal vector. If that matters to you, you should note that the vector you computed is in the correct direction, but its magnitude is greater than $1$. It can be made into a unit vector by multiplying by an appropriate scalar.

Answer (score 0):

Draw it.  $S$ is a cone with vertex at the origin.  As Parcly mentions in the comments, it has equation $z=r$ in cylindrical coordinates.  The vector $N$ at the point with cylindrical coordinates $(z,\theta,z)$ can be written as $-z \hat{\mathbf{r}} + z \hat{\mathbf{k}}$, where $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ is the unit vector pointing in the direction of increasing $r$.